# Keras Custom Loss Monitor

Tags: tensorflow, keras, model, training-data, loss-function

In a Keras model, I've created a custom loss where some parts of output is using MSE and some parts are using binary crossentropy.

```py
def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        y_true = tensorflow.convert_to_tensor(y_true)
        y_pred = tensorflow.convert_to_tensor(y_pred)

        numerical_data_loss = mean_squared_error(y_true[:, 0], y_pred[:, 0])
        binary_data_loss = binary_crossentropy(y_true[:, 1], y_pred[:, 1])

        loss = numerical_data_loss + binary_data_loss
        return loss
```

How can I monitor the contributing factors to my custom loss independently i.e one metric for MSE and one for binary crossentropy?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more googling:

The `metrics` kwarg of `model.fit` can accept a list of custom loss functions with the same signature as to the one you already write for the actual loss. You can break the loss function into separate individual loss functions and pass them to the metrics to observe each loss's contribution to the final loss and in the final loss function add them up for backpropagation.